Why does my male kitten (13 weeks) keep chasing and pouncing on the female (about 10 weeks)
My dad recently got 2 new kittens. Tiger (male) about 3 weeks ago, and Ren (female) today.
Tiger is A very rambunctious little boy, while Ren is much more mellow and a snuggle bean.  I brought Ren home today and before I could get the door to my room closed Tiger snuck out and its been problems since.
He instantly goes to her to say hi, and then start being a jerk. Pouncing on her and chasing her around every time she tries to run away. I was finally able to pick her up and walked away from it all (small cats are very fast little things) and he started growling and looking for her, running around the last area he saw her, almost like he was hunting for her.
I'm not sure if this matters but his ears are not back in aggression, there's no hissing prior to the pounce (from him at least) and he doesn't puff up in agitation.
Truly anything will help, thank you so much.

Are you aware that cats (especially male ones) are extremely territorial and you need to follow a whole process of introduction for them to accept other cats? Read more in reference 1 and reference 2. Neutered male cats are more tolerant than sexually intact ones and you'll have to desex at least one of them anyways if you don't want kittens.

Yes, the plan is to spay/neuter both kittens here in the next coming month or so. And yes, I do know that introducing cats can be a weeks-long situation. To be honest I never had any issues similar to this with my older male cat even before he was neutered. Thus why I was asking if this is normal behavior.

They're both kittens. Kittens play by fighting. If he's not showing signs of aggression, have you considered he's trying to play with her?
